# How to send a message to the chat in a VoiceChannel using discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I tried doing

```
channel = self.bot.get_channel(*voice channel id*)
await channel.send("Hello World")
```

but I can't send a message because it's a voice channel. I read the docs but there is no mention of how to send a message in a voice channel unless I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send message in a Voice channel like a Text channel
but you must use the latest version that you can install via this command in the terminal.

> pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

if you do that there's no reason why it shouldn't work.